# SpecFlow tags through XUnit on the command line

Tags: .net, specflow, xunit

Does Xunit support running subsets of SpecFlow Scenarios when running from the command line?

Looking at the generated code, it places the ignore tag in to the Fact attribute, but doesn't use the other custom tags?

If it was placing the tag in the Trait attribute we could filter through this, but the tags only seem to be used in the ScenarioInfo class

Comment: Which version of specflow are you using? I think the support around this might have imp[roved in v2, which is uin beta on nuget. try  that and see if it helps with your issue